# VS code cannot find -lgcc file

Tags: visual-studio-code

c_cpp_properties.json is

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include",
                    "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/MinGW/include/*",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            },
            "compilerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

My cpp file is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    string date = "2020.03.03";
    string year = date.substr(0,4);
    cout << year << endl;

    return 0;
};
```

When I build the test.cpp, there is error

```
./../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My System environment variable has "C:\MinGW\bin".
My gcc.exe and g++.exe path are added to c_cpp_properties.json correctly.
My .vscode is in Backtest project folder, and Test project folder does not have .vscode. (I think it is not problem...)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Assumption

1. System environment path is correct.
2. c_cpp_properties.json and tasks.json are correct.

After check the above assumption, if you have still problem, you need to reinstall MinGW.
I reinstalled that from https://winlibs.com/

Thank you.